# Given a root and divisor, how can I find the value of 2 variables in a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

Let $P\left(x\right)=x^3-2ax^2+bx+18$. Knowing that this polynomial is, in an instance, divisible by $x^2-x-6$, and in another, has a double root of -1, what are the values of a and b? I'm having problems solving this kind of problem. What's the best approach to solve these?

I know we're not really supposed to post textbook problems, but I'm learning math all by my own and I can't find an answer anywhere else. It would be very appreciated if you explain the full logic and implications for the solution and not merely an algorithm.

Comment: It is not possible for $P$ to have $Q(x)=x^2-x-6$ as a divisor and to have $-1$ as a double root: $-1$ is not a root of $Q$ and consider degrees.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net you're right, my bad, I already edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *and in another, has a double root of -1*. If you mean that $-1$ is a double root of $P$, then still it is impossible for $P$ to fulfill both conditions.

Comment: I mean, it's two different problems. Assume that in one instance it has $x2−x−6$ and in a different one has -1 as a root instead. Sorry for causing confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $$x^3-2ax^2+bx+18=(x^2-x-6)(x-c)$$
You will get the System $$18=6c$$, $$c-6=b$$,$$-c-1=-2a$$
Expanding the right side we get

$$x^3-x^2(c+1)+x(c-6)+6c$$ and now compare the coeficients.

Comment: How did you get that system? i.e.: How do you know 18 = 6c?

Comment: Thank for making it more clear. I can solve it now! But why did you write $(x-c)$ and not $(x+c)$ for instance, or anything else?

Comment: You can try it with $x+c$ it must give the same result i think, $c$ is only a variable.

Comment: Nice that your problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have two different problems there.  Telling you that $x^2-x-6$ is a factor is sufficient to determine $a$ and $b$, as is telling you that $-1$ is a double root.  You will get different values for $a$ and $b$ in the two cases.

For the first, just perform the division.  You need to have the second stage, the one involving $x^2$, come out even.  The constants will tell you what constant you are multiplying by and you need $a$ and $b$ correct to come out.

For the second, you are told that $(x+1)^2$ is a factor.  You can do it the same way, by division.

Comment: You mean polynomial long division? And what do you mean by 'second stage'?

Comment: Yes, I meant polynomial long division. The first stage is when you do the $x^3$ term, the second when you do $x^2$

Answer (score 0):

When it has a double root it has a common root with its derivative. Take derivative and and put $-1$ in it it gives you one equation.The roots of divisor are -3 and 2 .putting in polynomial gives two more equations which with first equation make a system of equation which gives a and b.I think it must have another constant to be found.